# How to validate syntax of Python2 code from Python3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, validation, syntax

I am in Python3. I have a bunch of Python2 `.py` files. For each of these files, I need to check whether the contents are valid Python2 code and return it as a boolean. The files are small scripts, sometimes they may import things or have a function or class, but mostly they are pretty simple.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you do it at build time? If so, you can try run `2to3` and parse its output to determine if the file is valid Python 2 code.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it at runtime.